# Optional fields when reading in JSON via DataContracts in C#

Tags: c#, json, twitter, datacontract

I am working with the Twitter API, accessing it via C# and DataContracts.

I have trouble reading in the geo field. The problem is that sometimes it contains sub fields, while sometimes it is null:

```
"geo":{"coordinates":[52.5112,13.3577],"type":"Point"}
```

or

```
"geo":null
```

I am trying it with

```
[DataContract]
public class Geo
{
  [DataMember(Name = "coordinates")]
  public string Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get is:

> "There was an error deserializing the object of type Twitter.SearchResults. End element 'coordinates' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''."

Seems like the parser hit a null, but expected a coordinates field. I understand that I told the parser to expect "coordinates", so of course it complains. But I do not know how I can make this field optional.

Comment: Have you tried with     public string Coordinates; rather than a property?

Comment: @ChrisBD: That's the wrong way to go. `DataContract` does not work with instance variables. It requires properties.

Comment: interesting when the MSDN examples do just that e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

Comment: @ChrisBD: You're right. Fields work as well. The restriction is that both fields and properties have to be public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, all properties/fields are optional by default. The problem rather seems to be that  coordinates isn't a string property, but an array of floating point numbers.

So to fix it, try:

```
[DataContract]
public class Geo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "coordinates")]
    public double[] Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```